# Powershell escaping single quotes

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

How can I escape the single quote in the below Powershell command?

```
Get-Recipient -Filter "Members -eq 'CN=Jane D'Amico (Contoso),OU=fourthcoffee.onmicrosoft.com,OU=Microsoft Exchange Hosted Organizations,DC=NAMPR1AA001,DC=PROD,DC=OUTLOOK,DC=COM'"
```

I suspect this is failing due to the `D'Amico`. Not a powershell person so please go easy on me.

Cannot bind parameter 'Filter' to the target. Exception setting "Filter": "Invalid
filter syntax.

Comment: I would try D`'Amico or swap the outer " and inner '

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're just passing a string (which you are), you can use doublequotes again, and escape it like so:

```
Get-Recipient -Filter "Members -eq `"CN=Jane D'Amico (Contoso),OU=fourthcoffee.onmicrosoft.com,OU=Microsoft Exchange Hosted Organizations,DC=NAMPR1AA001,DC=PROD,DC=OUTLOOK,DC=COM`""
```

Answer (score 1):

To escape quotes you need to double them up, so D'Amico needs to become D''Amico.

A good way to handle this would be to assign your user string to a variable first

```
$user = "CN=Jane D'Amico (Contoso),OU=fourthcoffee.onmicrosoft.com,OU=Microsoft Exchange Hosted Organizations,DC=NAMPR1AA001,DC=PROD,DC=OUTLOOK,DC=COM"
```

then replace any single quotes inside before using it

```
$user = $user -replace "'", "''"    
Get-Recipient -Filter "Members -eq '$user'"
```